# Will setting an uninitialized mapping value to 0 cost gas?

Tags: solidity, gas

Say I have a mapping:

`mapping (address => bytes32) public someMapping;`

I then set `someMapping[msg.sender] = 0`

(let's say that address has never been set before). Will that cost gas, or will it figure out that no action is required?

Answer (score 1):

Like all the actions that require a computation to be done by miners and that could change the state of the contract => It will cost a certain amount of gas, I tried quickly in remix with the following contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Test {

    mapping (uint256 => address) aMapping;

    function set() public {
        aMapping[1] = this;
    }

    function testA() public  {
        aMapping[0] = 0;
    }

        function testB() public  {
        aMapping[1] = 0;
    }

            function testC() public  {
        aMapping[2] = 0;
    }
}
```

And it costed me a little bit of gas each time I called testA/testB/testC

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out and see if it's worth checking for a 0 value before simply writing 0.